# What is the best way to approximate average current or count battery amp-hours?

Tags: current-measurement

I'm using an INA214 current sense opamp to measure current flowing through a 100A shunt, which is on the low side of a 12V battery bank. The readings are stable under stable load, but vary greatly when the load is either pulse-width modulated, or AC via an inverter.

When I aggregate the opamp output (mV over the shunt = current levels) and calculate the average, the readings are again relatively stable. However, it seems necessary to have a very high sample rate, thus occupying the MCU almost constantly.

Is there a simpler/better way to get a value that represents average current (Ah/h)?

Comment: Average is defined by Time interval. Accumulated average can be integrate , sample and dump to reduce sampling rate for example. or digitally done by Coulomb counters with integrate, increment count (IRQ) and reset integrator.

Comment: Use an "analog integrator". Basically a low pass filter.

Comment: It depends if you need to sample both I and I*t for different reasons

Comment: Is this for bidirectional current, single supply?

Comment: INA240 has built-in PWM rejection on its inputs. Maybe you can give it a try.

Comment: I changed to title to include both questions, averaging current and Amp-hr counting because Ah is not average current but accumulated average current yet Ah/h is just Amps with a Low pass filter and fixed DC gain not an integrator.

Comment: Specs in question need to include time frame of desired output and spectrum of current (BW) to ensure there is no conflict with Nyquist sampling theory.

Comment: While not directly answering your question, the challenge you present is real and while surmountable by filtering or averaging the current, you're still left with compounding errors. Columb counting for measuring a battery's state of charge has become an antiquated technique and thus I highly recommend investigating impedance track[ing] methods as a more reliable alternative.

Comment: @ngm_code, Is impedance tracking also relevant for lithium batteries? I know it's used for lead acid batteries, but they themselves have, too, become antiquated.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, Range is 0-100A, ideally 1%-error resolution especially around 0-10A and 1-5%-error from 10-100A. What matters most is the precise coulomb counting. The solutions presented here, using a low pass filter, using an IC, or perhaps programming a small MCU for the purpose, together with a high-sample-rate ADC (e.g. 10kHz) should do the trick? Although I'm using 10-20kHz PWM, and I assume the inverter has similar high frequency switching, so perhaps analog averaging is really essential.

Comment: Nothing else I see here will work (meet all specs) except the IC that I suggested and method in the 1st place with Coulomb counting. What do you not understand?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, Sounds good, thanks :)

Comment: @user95482301 yes, the impedance track methodology is the latest and greatest way to gauge Li-Ion batteries. I've built systems that follow these algorithms and TI offers silicon with the functionality built in (they are using it to replace their old coulomb counters). It can be stable over temperature, avoids compounding errors and places little to no burden on the user for maintenance calibrations. When properly implemented it avoids the sudden shutdown problems or unexpected fuel gauging errors associated with voltage based systems or non-ideal coloumb counters.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a low pass filter, to keep the average DC component of your sense signal.

You would have to tune the filter to the level of smoothness you want at the trade of settling time.

You may want to feed both to the micro though so you can measure both average and instantaneous levels.

Benefit of analog is also you do not miss spikes that may be in tune with your sampling time.

Comment: I would go for a leaky integrator over a straight integrator because... DC will wind it up

Comment: @JonRB, yes some tuning is required.

Comment: The practical problems with an integrator include offset voltage ,  Cap leakage RC time constant and then the need to reset before saturation ( discharge C) as well as low or high side Common Mode range of Op Amp, single supply or dual supply with bipolar currents.

Comment: Indeed @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, it takes a little tuning as I said. But on the other hand, a digital solution has practical issues with beat frequencies and errors due to synchronization. It really depends on what the OP intends to use the value for.

Comment: An integrator however does not measure Amps but Amp second with a current shunt R

Comment: @Trevor, The intended use is particularly estimation of SoC of Lithium batteries, but also having insight in average current realtime. Could you elaborate more on how the MCU would read the output of the opamp? Would you have to calculate the time between samples, rise time, time between saturation, or?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, Or rather, mV-seconds?

Comment: same thing as volt-seconds but with mV/A current shunt you want Ah or amp-seconds whatever , in any case it wont do the job as is

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75, sigh you are right, I am getting confused with the function... It has been a long day

Comment: Corrected answer to use Low pass filter instead...

Comment: @Trevor, Using a calculator, I arrive at 10k Ohm, 1uF = ~16 Hz. Is this a reasonable starting point? I assume high impedance can be a problem, but with lower impedance, the capacitor would have to be higher, which in turn would cause higher current draw from the opamp.

Answer (score 2):

### I to mV to low f digital Coulomb counter

[image]

Output is fed to uC counter by IRQ or master slave register on each pulse sent (Set) and read (Reset)

32.55Hz/V = Charge Count Frequency using external 50mV shunt for rated max current, R sense like 50 mΩ for 50mV/1A

[image]

The question is ambiguous because of the Ah/h is just amps and time interval is unspecified.

But an integrator will just saturate unless you have low (e.g. <0.5mV) input offset, low cap leakage current and a comparator and switch to dump charge etc.

Average current is simply a LPF ( with any gain you wish)

Comment: Hmmm.. interesting ...

Comment: As I understand it, Ampere = Coloumb / second.  Thus Ah/h is thus Coloumb/hour. The unit thus more clearly represents a long term average, than Ampere would. You could also write it C/h, but I think it would be more confusing.

Comment: @user95482301 as I understand it this circuit gives you a count of blocks of charge passing, The micro would need to track tame and do the math to indicate the amperage.

Comment: @user95482301  That is correct but if you measure Amps or Coulombs/sec then you run into the problem you stated with CPU sampling rate, Nyquist filter etc, If you Integrate, then you saturate output with Vdc so you have to detect threshold, dump and count. So the chip above is simplest solution to count pulses using V=I*Rs and output = 32.55Hz/V.     But you need to specify time frame for results. Do you want to measure Amps every ms or compute mA-h every minute or what?

Comment: Producing a low tach frequency means pulse rate is proportional to Current and counting pulses is proportional to Coulombs.